# How to add an auto incremented primary key as a foreign key to existing database tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I got three mysql database tables which are properly connected using foreign keys constraints as shown below:

[image: Current Database Schema]

But the problem is the foreign key constrained with fields that are not integer and auto increment type instead they are all of varchar type.

I am trying not prevent re-doing the mapping again for these tables which area already correctly mapped but instead want to add a new primary and foreign keys that are integer type and unique. So that all data remain the same in all the tables. Please let me know if any way I can run a script that can auto map existing tables with a new primary and foreign keys.

I tried to add a primary key on base tables

```
ALTER TABLE videofile ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key;
```

This will add a new Primary key to the base table but I want the newly added primary key as FK to other tables based on existing mapped keys and data. Please let me know if there exist any script to customize this need.

Comment: Why do you feel the need for the row identifier? Are there storage or other considerations that are driving the change?

Comment: @bbaird: As some java script libraries need int field to bind data rather than text that is triggering this issue now

Comment: Aren't they many:many -- That is a video has many subjects and a subject is associated with many videos?

Comment: This task requires custom code.  You'll need to 1) Drop the foreign key constraints.  2) Add the identifier to the subject table.  3) Add the identifier to the video table.  4) Add the identifier to the elan table.  5) Create the foreign keys for the video table.  6) Create the foreign keys for the elan table.  7) Drop the existing foreign keys.  8) Add the new foreign keys and foreign key restraints.  9) Drop the primary indexes and create the new primary indexes.

Comment: @RickJames: in my case this is one:many relation that works fine for my usecase.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: can you direct some resources on how? adding manual id how can we get the exising related values and maintain the similar relation to the new PK-FK relations.

Comment: Pick a programming language that supports SQL.  Like I said, the task requires custom code that's tested and retested.  You could try doing this through Workbench, but it's too easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This will require rebuilding the tables, so you'll have to rip off the bandaid.  As always, test the DDL **before making the changes.**

1. Create a new version of the tables with the new key structure:`SubjectId`/`VideoId`/`<whatever>Id` as the primary key, the **old primary key as an alternate key (unique constraint)**.  We'll refer to them with the suffix _new.
2. Lock the tables or take the database offline.
3. Load the data from `Subject` into `Subject_New` first.  Then, join `Subject_New` to `Video` to get the new key to insert into `Video_New`.
4. Repeat the same step for the table dependent on `Video`.
5. Disable any dependencies/constraints from the old tables and apply those to the new tables.
6. [Rename](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html) the old tables to `<table>_old` and drop the _new suffix from the tables you just created.
7. Bring things back online.

Comment: do you thing the new PK-FK will keep the existing tables' relationships? even adding the new ones.

Comment: As long as you ensure you have a unique constraint on the old PK column, the new column acts as a *surrogate* for that key and as long as you associate that surrogate to the child table it will effectively enforce the prior relationships.

Comment: When you create the new versions of the table, you will create the FK constraints needed to enforce the relations using the new PK, and you will do that before you insert any data.